# How can I implement simultaneous deployment of backend and frontend?

Tags: deployment

everyone.

The company I work for is using nestjs as the backend and vue.js as the frontend, and the front and backend teams are using different GitHub repositories respectively.

When deploying, both the front and back ends use the GitHub action to reflect it in dev -> stage -> main.

The problem is that when deploying, the deployment completion time of the front end and the back end does not match, causing inconvenience to users when using the app.

To solve the problem, we distribute it at dawn when the amount of use is low, or the front team is distributing it by calculating (?) the distribution completion time of the backend team.

I know these methods are weird, and I want to improve them, but I can't think of a way. How can I fix the problem?